# Using ionic + Cordova in visual studio i keep getting "No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher."

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have seen a lot of posts about this, but none of the solutions in those posts solve my problem.
I have installed the android sdk according to how it should be installed and added the ANDROID_SDK_ROOT system variable.

Here's my folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdX3y.png)

And here's my system variables
[System Variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abyZg.png)

If go to powershell and type `sdkmanager --list --verbose` it will list all of my installed packages and it includes all of the build tools. yet when i run `ionic cordova run android --verbose --no-native-run` in visual studio i get the following error:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\android-sdk-windows (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Android\sdk
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
Where:
Script 'C:\ProyectoTFG\IonicProject\MonitorApp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\cordova.gradle' line: 64

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No installed build tools found. Install the Android build tools version 19.1.0 or higher.
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get it to work wit the standalone android sdk. I had to uninstall it and install android studio.